# The $cfg['TempDir'] (./tmp/) is not accessible. phpMyAdmin is not able to cache templates and will be slow because of this. Mac solution

Tags: macos, phpmyadmin, xampp, directory, lampp

I am using XAMPP and one day I was on PhpMyAdmin and saw this error message:

The $cfg['TempDir'] (./tmp/) is not accessible. phpMyAdmin is not able to cache templates and will be slow because of this.

I know you have to add a folder except the folder called PhpMyAdmin in LAMPP won't let me add folders. When I tried to change the permission settings in "Get Info" It just changed itself back to "Read only" instead of "Read and Write".

I will appreciate any help.

PS. I am using a Mac.

Comment: Also is there a way to get to LAMPP from the terminal?

Comment: Do you have any idea what `$cfg[`'TempDir'] refers to? If so, what are the permissions? If not, can you trace PhpMyAdmin to find out what's going on?

Comment: I figured out my issue. I was looking at the mac terminal rather than the XAMPP terminal. Whoops! Thanks anyway for answering my question though.

Comment: Does *looking* at a different terminal fix access to the `TempDir`?

Comment: Yes looking at the one that comes with xampp does the trick.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

I had this problem with XAMPP 7.3.3-1 today after running a test with mysqli_real_escape_string (maybe a coincidence, I don't know).

This solved my problem:

Stop the services.

Create a /tmp folder under the phpmyadmin folder, using the Terminal:

```
sudo mkdir -p /Applications/XAMPP/xamppfiles/phpmyadmin/tmp/
```

Then I changed the permissions similar to (but not exactly) like the Xampp support suggested at https://community.bitnami.com/t/the-cfg-tempdir-tmp-is-not-accessible/60376.

```
sudo chown daemon /Applications/XAMPP/xamppfiles/phpmyadmin/tmp/
sudo chmod 775 /Applications/XAMPP/xamppfiles/phpmyadmin/tmp/
```

Then restart both Mysql Database and Apache WebServer.

Hope this helps.